# problem for import with pimgento

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, data

I have this error when i try to import my categorie.csv in magento with the module pimgento (in the menu import pim data)

> General error: 1290 The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

If someone can help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change your MySQL server configuration, you can disable the use of "Load Data file" by Pimgento configuration:
Go to System > Configuration > Pimgento > General
and change "CSV: Use MySql Load Data File" option to "No".